# If one variable is selected or another is selected display block of html

Tags: javascript, html

I need to update my code so if one variable or another is selected they both display the same html table. I don't want them to show two tables at the same time but one on if either or both are selected.

I've tried:

```
function enableaddonservice() {
    var ecom =document.getElementById("Apply_ECOM_Check").checked;
    var moto =document.getElementById("Apply_MOTO_Check").checked;

    if (ecom || moto ==true ) {
        document.getElementById("addonservices").style.display = "block";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("addonservices").style.display = "none";
    }
}

 <input class="noborder" type="checkbox" ID="Apply_ECOM_Check" name="Apply_ECOM_Check" runat="server" style="width: 18px" value="ON" onClick="enableaddonservice();" /> ECOM &nbsp;&nbsp;
               <input class="noborder" type="checkbox" ID="Apply_MOTO_Check" name="Apply_MOTO_Check" runat="server" style="width: 18px" value="ON" onClick="enableaddonservice();" /> MOTO &nbsp;&nbsp;
               <input class="noborder" type="checkbox" ID="Apply_TERMINAL_Check" name="Apply_TERMINAL_Check" runat="server" style="width: 18px" value="ON" onClick="enableaddonservice()" /> TERMINAL


     <div id="addonservices" name="addonservices" style="display:block;">

  <table style="width: 100%">
                      <tr>
                                     <td><input class="noborder" type="checkbox" ID="Apply_PayLink" name="Apply_PayLink" runat="server" style="width: 18px"  /> Pay-Link &nbsp;&nbsp;</td>

                          <td> <input class="noborder" type="checkbox" ID="Apply_Mobilepaypage" name="Apply_Mobilepaypage" runat="server" style="width: 18px"  /> Mobile PayPage &nbsp;&nbsp; </td>
                          <td> <input class="noborder" type="checkbox" ID="Apply_RepeatPayments" name="Apply_RepeatPayments" runat="server" style="width: 18px"  /> Repeat Payments &nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
                      </tr>
```

Comment: `if (ecom || moto)` would evaluate to `true` if either of them is true, you don't need the `== true`. The rest of your question is not clear, you could consider editing to let other users know what you are asking. Adding your `HTML` would also help, it would be even better if you could make a snippet and show us where you are not getting the expected results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's best practice to use `classList` to assign classes to an element when toggling between 'states'.

Using "classList", you can add or remove a class without affecting any others the element may have. But if you assign "className", it will wipe out any existing classes while adding the new one (or if you assign an empty string it will wipe out all of them). [source](https://teamtreehouse.com/community/difference-between-classlist-and-classname).

Take a look at the following example:

```js
document.addEventListener('change', (e) => document.querySelectorAll('div')
  .forEach(d => {
    d.id === e.target.value ?
      d.classList.add('is-active') :
      d.classList.remove('is-active');
  })
);
```

```css
div {
  display: none;
}

.is-active {
  display: block !important;
}
```

```html
<div id="ecom">
  Ecom content
</div>
<div id="moto">
  Moto content
</div>
<input type="radio" name="mode" value="ecom" /> Ecom
<br/>
<input type="radio" name="mode" value="moto" /> Moto
```

Comment: I want to display the same content for both ecom and moto but never to be shown at the same time. So click ecom show content 1, click moto show content 1, click both show only content 1 and not 2 instances of content 1. Showing different content for each selection will mean I have to have different id's and this will mess up my php file.

Comment: Then you have to use a radio button :) See updated code example

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample. You need to disable it initially and then show only if the either of the checkboxes are checked

```js
document.getElementById("addonservices").style.display = "none";

function enableaddonservice() {

  var ecom = document.getElementById("Apply_ECOM_Check").checked;
  var moto = document.getElementById("Apply_MOTO_Check").checked;


  if (ecom || moto) {
    document.getElementById("addonservices").style.display = "block";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("addonservices").style.display = "none";
  }


}
```

```html
ECOM : <input type="checkbox" id="Apply_ECOM_Check" /> MOTO : <input type="checkbox" id="Apply_MOTO_Check" />

<button onclick="enableaddonservice()">Submit</button>

<table id="addonservices">
  <tr>
    <td>test</td>
    <td> table</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I did it. It worked if I removed the `    ==true` from ` if (ecom || moto ==true )` Thanks for your help guys.